# Shifting signals in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to implement a system to recognize numbers between 0-9. I have a TemplateSet and a TestSet of recorded audio signals of numbers between 0-9. I have to do cross correlation between all audio files to find the best similarity between them. After that, I should do time shifting for each signal to synchronize it in order to compare it to other signals to get the best result. I don't know how to implement time-shifting.

```
MaxSize=[0,0];
for i=1:9
    TempSize=size(temp{i});
    TestSize=size(test{i});
    if(TempSize(1)>MaxSize(1))
        MaxSize(1)=TempSize(1);

    end
    if(TestSize(1)>MaxSize(1))
        MaxSize(1)=TestSize(1); 
    end

end

for j=1:9
    TsSize=(MaxSize-size( temp{j}));

    TpSize=(MaxSize-size( test{j}));
   temp{j}(end+TsSize)=0;
    test{j}(end+TpSize)=0;


end
%------------ Euclidean distance-----
sum=0;
 index=zeros(1,9); 
 Distance=zeros(9,9);
for m =1:9
   MinDistance=10000;

    for n=1:9
      Distance(m,n)= norm(test{m}-temp{n},2);
     if (Distance< MinDistance)
        index(m,n)=n;
          MinDistance=Distance;   
     end 
    end

   if(index(m)==m)
          sum=sum+1;
    end    
end

%--------------------------------------------------------------

TimeDiff=zeros(9,9);
for l=1:9
    for k=1:9
      [c,lag]=xcorr(test{l},temp{k});
      TimeDiff(l,k)=max(abs(c));

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%euclidean distance

 index=zeros(1,10); 

 Distance=zeros(10,10);

 for m =1:10
   MinDistance=10000;
    for n=1:10
      Distance(m,n)= norm(test{m}-temp{n},2);
     if (Distance < MinDistance)
        index(m,n)=n;
         MinDistance=Distance;   
     end 
    end

end

TimeDiff=zeros(10,10);
euclidean =zeros(10,10);

for l=1:10
    for i=1:10
      [c,lag]=xcorr(test{l},temp{i});
      [~,I]= max(abs(c));  
      shifted= circshift(test{1},I);
      euclidean(l,k)=norm(temp{l}-shifted,2);
    end
end

%.................................................

Index=0;
for i=1:10
    Min=1000000;
    for j=1:10
      if( euclidean(i,j)<Min ) 
          Min=euclidean(i,j);
          index=j;
      end 
    end

end
```

then cross correlate the signal.